# inserting data from dropdown list in mySql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a form in which a user inserts data like first name,last name, age,mail and location and these values are updated in a database.All the variables are inserted through text but the location one is a dropdown list. The form.php file is like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
mail:<input type="text" name="mail">
Location:<select name="education">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option></select>:<br />

<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the insert.php file:

```
<?php

$firstname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']));
$lastname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']));
$age = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']));
$mail = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']));
$location = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']));


$sql="INSERT INTO persons (firstname, lastname, age, mail, location)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]', '$_POST[mail]','$_POST[location]')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I try to use this I get a message saying:

> Notice: Undefined index: Location in C:\xampp\htdocs\family_guy\insert.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Location in C:\xampp\htdocs\family_guy\insert.php on line 16
> 1 record added

All the values except location are saved in the database.
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Change `<select name="education">` to `<select name="location">`

Comment: Plus, you're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_real_escape_string` they do not mix. This requires a complete rewrite, and I'm not up to eating what's on the fish and birds' menu; **IF** y'all know what I mean ;)

Comment: Also the mysql_real_escape_string lines do not have any effect, since you use $_POST[...] in the $sql statement and not the escaped values.

Comment: Your `escape()` calls are utterly USELESS. You use them incorrectly, then utterly ignore the escaped values in your query and use the original raw unescaped values anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: The reason why you can't get the value for Location in `$_POST['location']` is, that the form field is named `education`. Change it to `location` and it'll work. - The name attribute in the HTML tags are the keys for the `$_POST` array - thus those have to match (even with casing).

Second: SQL Injections are possible with your code. You escape the user entered data `$firstname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']));`, however, you use the unescaped data in `$sql`. You have to use

```
$sql="INSERT INTO persons (firstname, lastname, age, mail, location)
VALUES
('$firstname','$lastname','$age', '$mail','$location')";
```

or even better prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Third: You should not mix mysqli_* and mysql_* API calls.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.i will check the prepared statements too.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong word here

```
Location:<select name="education">
```

Change it to

```
Location:<select name="location">
```

Comment: @george123 I suggest you learn how to do [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). They are easier in my opinion and secure from sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your location fiel has the name `education`. change this to `location`

is:

```
Location:<select name="education">
```

should be

```
Location:<select name="location">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

Starting with `<select name="education">` and `$_POST['location']` which should most likely and be what you intend it to be `<select name="location">` - you're using the wrong name for it.

- *Next thing,* is the use of a **[`mysql_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)** based function => `mysql_real_escape_string`.

in, and all others using `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$firstname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']));
```

which should read as (while applying the same function syntax for the others)

```
$firstname = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['firstname']));
```

Both `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions do not mix together during the execution of code (on the same page) or using a `mysqli_` based DB connection, which is what yours is.

`mysqli_query($con,$sql)`

So now you need to make sure that you've successfully placed your DB connection before using `$firstname = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['firstname']));` etc.

Plus, use the variables `$firstname` etc, instead of doing `('$_POST[firstname]'...)";`

as in `('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age', '$mail', '$location')`.

Because in using `$_POST[firstname]'` etc. in your VALUES, you're not using the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function, nor using the POST data; it just lays there, doing nothing.

***Sidenote*** about `mysql_real_escape_string()` - which should be `mysqli_` based as previously stated.

---

With that said, do [**use prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) , or **PDO** with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), it's safer ;)

Plus, add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) after your opening `<?php` tag.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which will trigger/show any errors found.

---

Related functions links:

- **[`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)** - what you should be using.
- **[`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)** - does not mix with `mysqli_`